# .htaccess Multiple rewrite conds from swapped directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have this media wiki installation on the root /public_html/ directory and I have since the beginning used rewrite engine on htaccess (as suggested [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)) to redirect my site, for example (domain.com) to (domain.com/wiki/) with the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

I also have a wordpress installation on the public_html/site/ directory.
What I wanna do is keep the wiki rewrite rule, **except** for the main domain and I wanna add another rewrite rule that would do the same for the wordpress installation but rewriting for the main domain.

So accessing

- domain.com/about-us would display whats on domain.com/site/about-us
- domain.com would display whats on domain.com/site
- domain.com/wiki would still function the same way, just the root domain would display the wordpress site instead of the wiki.

What would be the way to add this second rewrite rule for the site and keep the wiki one **except** for the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to try it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ site [L]
```

**Make sure you have a .htaccess file for wordpress in the** `site` **folder with the correct rewritebase.**

I personally would have different domains for these. Like `wiki.example.com` instead of all these rewrites. Which can then have it's own SEO rep.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  What do you mean by the correct rewritebase tho?

Also I would have had different subdomains if this was thought beforehand but the truth is that the wiki was created long before the site and its now massive with a lot of backlinks to the /wiki/ pages so changing link structure and breaking the thousands of backlinks  that already exist wouldn't really be worth it.

Comment: If WP is in site, then you need to use `RewriteBase /site` and the  `RewritwRule . /site/index.php [L]` in that .htaccess file. Also if this helped you please accept the answer.

Comment: Hey there, I finally got to try your solution, and the wiki ended up messing up big time, stylesheets, and some images are not working properly (http://comp.tf/wiki) and the rewriterule ended up only redirecting the main domain (in this case comp.tf, to comp.tf/site instead of rewriting them without the /site) is there any issue with the htaccess that might be causing this?

Comment: Use absolute paths for your assets.  Or in the head section of the html for wiki add `<base href="/wiki" />`which should help fix the stylesheet image issue.